# Cannot find a JSP variable in debug mode

Tags: java, jsp, debugging, netbeans

In my JSP file I have a property initialized like this:

```
<c:set var="perspectiveCount" value="0"/>
```

I am trying to learn how to debug JSP in NetBeans.
When I toggle a breakpoint just after that line and debug the program I get a plethora of variables in the Variables tab where I cannot find `perspectiveCount`. Maybe because it's not exactly a variable, but a property.

I also tried to use Evaluate Code tab, but it answers me "perspectiveCount" is not a known variable in the current context.

What is the correct way to debug and learn the value of `perspectiveCount`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/40556256/548473 for auto completion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NetBeans debugger doesn't see JSP vars as variables that can be evaluated directly. They are context attributes. So, the method that worked for met was to enter

```
pageContext.findAttribute("perspectiveCount")
```

in the "Evaluate Code" tab. After doing so and clicking on "Evaluate Code Fragment" button debugger added `pageContext.findAttribute("perspectiveCount")` to the "Variables" tab and showed its value there.

Answer (score 15):

Althought you debug with Netbeans, this might be helpful to others:

On Intellij **pageContext** appears and dissappears from debug as a local variable. You can relay on **_jspx_page_context**

then

```
_jspx_page_context.findAttribute("perspectiveCount")
```

will let you debug what you want on Intellij.