# Debugging inside a JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-webflow

I'm using Java 1.6, Spring 3.4, Spring Webflow 2.3.2 and Tomcat 7.   I'm trying to debug a JSP page which uses EL expressions like:

```
<c:if test="${myObject.myThing == SomeClass.ENUMVALUE.myvalue}"  >
```

The `myObject` object is passed in as the Webflow model object.  I have a breakpoint set on this line and I am able to reach it and break on it, but anything I try to "watch" or "evaluate" gives me an error message.   I get either

```
${myObject.myThing == SomeClass.ENUMVALUE.myvalue}:  Invalid Expression

myObject.myThing:  Type is unknown for 'myObject'

(MyCorrectType) myObject:  Cannot find local variable 'myObject'
```

How the heck can I find this model object?   What is it contained in by the time it reaches the JSP page?

Comment: If done correctly, it will be in the `HttpServletRequest` attributes.

Comment: How are you passing myObject to the JSP? Could we see that code?

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be in the request, which was not very intuitive.  I've documented what I found in the answer below.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that it will be in the `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request` object (In my particular case, it was buried several levels deep inside wrapper objects.)

If you are using a debugger, like the one in Intellij (which I use), you can get the value of an individual attribute (like the Webflow model object) by evaluating the expression `request.getAttribute("attributeName")`.   Note that this may return a Java Object type, and you may have to cast it to the correct type.

For example, in my case, I was able to find the value of the value I wanted using this expression:

```
((MyObject)(request.getAttribute("myObject"))).getMyThing()
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

In IDEA 2016.2 `request` in JSP debug doesn't work anymore:(

It is possible to get attribute as

```
_jspx_page_context.request.getAttribute("...")
```

(inside tag as `parentTag.requestContext.request.getAttributeNames()`)

It's also possible add in project dependency on jasper with provided scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.47</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and use auto completion:

[image]